# Pattern Programmings

Tags: c, algorithm, logic

I am having difficulty understanding the logic behind drawing patterns with `*` and numbers in C.

For example, I am drawing this pattern:

```
  *  
 * *  
** **
 * *
  *
```

Some things that I understand in this programs are to take various `for` loops for printing `*` and whitespaces, but it's getting difficult to determine the conditions for them.

In the above example I think I need to draw half the triangle and the remaining is the reverse of it.

So please help me to understand the logic I should consider to draw such patterns every time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i,j=0,k,l,m,o,n=6;
    clrscr();
    printf(" ");
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        for(j=2;j>0;j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
            for(k=0;k<=(2*i);k++)
            {
                printf("*");
                //  getch();
            }
        }
        //  getch();
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

This is how I tried coding, I am not getting the conditions for nested `for` loop.

Comment: Show the code you have tried. Somebody might be able help you from there.

Comment: @RSahu The code for the above pattern is not important for me, I want to understand the logic to draw such patterns like how many FOR loops should I use, What conditions should i use for space and printing *.

Comment: Typically the code will have two nested `for` loops. The outer loop handles the rows.  The inner loop handles the columns. Beyond that, no one can say unless you precisely specify the rules that govern the pattern.

Comment: @amish Welcome to the StackOverflow. The reason you are getting less response is because you haven't shown your efforts. For better and quick response, always show your effort and your specific problem.

Comment: @MohitJain I am new to Stack Overflow & I am trying to code this from last night continuously. I am failing to get that output, therefore I had asked for logic to draw any pattern programs and for explanation I provided that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{

    int n=3,i,j,k,l,m;
    clrscr();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            printf(" ");
        for(k=0;k<=i-1;k++)
            printf("*",k+1);
        for(m=0;m<1;m++)
        {
            if(i<=0)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        for(l=i-1;l>=0;l--)
            printf("*",l+1);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
            printf(" ");
        for(k=0;k<n-i-2;k++)
            printf("*",k+1);
        for(m=0;m<1;m++)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {}
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        for(l=1;l>0;l--)
            printf("*",l+1);
        printf("\n");
    }  
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally I got my solution by myself.

Comment: +1: Good you worked hard and got the answer. Avoid using `conio.h`, `clrscr` and `getch` because these functions are compiler extensions to the language, not part of C. So use them only when you really need those and not while learning.

Comment: @MohitJain `clrscr` is to clear the output screen before printing the output and `getch` to wait after printing the whole program. I didn't get you whats wrong in that.
I am using Tc in dosbox.

Comment: Both of these are non standard. That means, if you use stdio.h and printf, they are available on every compliant C compiler and you can port your code easily. But conio.h is an extension and available only for few targets and thus make your code non-portable. For such small programs you can use [ideone](http://ideone.com/IKFPRx) to stick with comparatively more standard C environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
        -2  -1  0   1   2
      +---+---+---+---+---+
   -2 | . | . | X | . | . |
      +---+---+---+---+---+
   -1 | . | X | O | X | . |
      +---+---+---+---+---+
    0 | X | X | O | X | X |
      +---+---+---+---+---+
    1 | . | X | O | X | . |
      +---+---+---+---+---+
    2 | . | . | X | . | . |
      +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Points are not drawn if (col = 0 and abs(row) != 2) or either row or col is 2 and other is non-zero. You can implement these conditions in your code.

```
For(row = -2 to 2)
  For(col = -2 to 2)
    if ( (col = 0 and abs(row) != 2) or (abs(row) = 2 and col != 0) or (abs(col) = 2 and row != 0) )
      draw space character
    else
      draw *
  line break
```